# Search a particular String in entire Mysql table(All fields)

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am currently working with below query with single field search

```
SELECT *
FROM user_college_tbl
WHERE college_name LIKE '%Impulse%';
```

How to Search a particular String in entire table(All fields)?

Comment: I think then you could do a dynamic sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into using full text search:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_college_tbl
WHERE MATCH(col1, col2, ...) AGAINST ('Impulse' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

This would assume that you had full text indices setup on all the text columns you wanted to be included in the search:

```
CREATE TABLE user_college_tbl (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    college_name VARCHAR(200),
    col1 TEXT,
    col2 TEXT,
    -- ... more text columns
    FULLTEXT(college_name, col1, col2, ...)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 5.6 or you don't want full text search, then you may be limited to ORing together `LIKE` expressions for each text column in the table, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_college_tbl
WHERE college_name LIKE '%Impulse%' OR
      col1 LIKE '%Impulse%' OR
      col2 LIKE '%Impulse%'
```

Comment: `FULLTEXT ` is not supporting

Comment: Are you saying that your database does not support full text search?  What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Yes. Mysql version is 5.5

Comment: Is there any other simple and easy solution?

Comment: Without full text search, you may be limited to using `LIKE` on each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
select
  group_concat(
    concat(
       column_name, '', ' like \'%Impulse%\' or '
    ) separator ''
  ) into @query
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'user_college_tbl';

set @query = concat('select * from user_college_tbl where ', 
           left(@query, length(@query) - 4));


prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: I am looking for easy solution.

Comment: This is not a tough solution at all

Comment: Here by using dynamic sql query, you don't need to give each column name directly